# Ошибка NullPointerException при вызове метода rawQuery на БД

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Мне нужно создать `Activity` для изменении данных на БД. Примерный алгоритм :
1) Из первого активити отправляется `id` записи на второй. 
2) На втором активити получаем данные из БД по `id` номеру. 
3) Изменяем их и записываем обратно.

Етап 1 работает как надо. А вот на втором этапе приложение крашится. Вот так я получаю данные:

```
nomrecik = intent.getStringExtra("id");

    cursor =  mSqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("select * from "+ DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_TABLE+" WHERE `_ID` = "+nomrecik, null);
    String[] headers = new String[] {DatabaseHelper.SITE_NAME_COLUMN, DatabaseHelper.LOGIN_COLUMN,DatabaseHelper.PASSWORD_COLUMN};

    website.setText(headers[0]);
    login.setText(headers[1]);
```

Причина ошибки на Стектрейсе:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])' on a null object reference
```

Comment: У вас `mSqLiteDatabase` `null`. Покажите как вы инициализируете БД перед тем, как у неё вызвать метод.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб спасибо за помощь. Я забыл указать имя базы. Теперь работает. Сейчас добавлю ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решении проблемы надо было добавить всего 2 строки. **Сначала** указать имя базы данных вот так:

```
mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this, "mydatabase.db", null, 1);
```

Потом получить эту базу для чтении(или записи) вот так:

```
mSqLiteDatabase = mDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
```

Уже после этих двух строк можно смело сделать запрос на БД. Работать будет.